# AngularJS $http get method and Laravel show()

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel-5

Here is what I am trying to do:

Angularjs

```
$http.get("/api/comments/"+id)
              .success(function(data){
                   $scope.comments = data;       
              })
```

And I have in laravel /api/comments/id route...

How can I take params with angularjs for example if user visit this url; `/home/1` I need to take `1` and send to angular get request?

Comment: Are you using $stateProvider or $routeProvider?

Comment: How is your routes defined in your application?

Comment: Vladimir, do you have route configuration in your angular javascript code?

Comment: No... I need help with it... (:

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `$stateProvider` like

```
$stateProvider
    .state('comments', {
        url: "/api/comments/:id",
        templateUrl: 'comments.html'
    })
```

You can take out the id using `$stateParams.id`

Or if you are using `$routeProvider` like;

```
$routeProvider 
    .when("/api/comments/:id"{
        templateUrl: 'comments.html'
    })
```

You can take out the id using `$routeParams.id`

Comment: I am new to angularjs could you explain me in more details how to define routes?

Comment: I don't need to take id from api I need to take id from /home/id and than send get request to /api/comments/id

Comment: Any how you have to configure routes in your application to get it done

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution is to inject `$routeParams` in your controller. And then set

```
app.controller(controllerName, function ($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
    $scope.id = $routeParams.id; 
}
```

You will then get `$scope.id = 1` when `visiting api/comments/1`

Comment: I need when user visit /home/1 to take 1 and submit to get req with that api.

Comment: this will work always. Updated the answer. Please see

Comment: Which is the controller you are accessing while going to the /home/1 page?

Comment: Can you log $routeparams also?

Comment: It just return undefined... Here is my whole code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31858415/how-to-configure-routes-angularjs

Comment: You please check, i have answered there

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using router a dirty way is to get it from [$location service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) and regexp integer from `$location.path()`.