# How to configure routes AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I need to pass id from project/id to CommentCtrl, when I try to `console.log($routeParams.id)` it return undefined... Anyone can find what wrong with my code?

```
   .config(function($routeProvider) {
                    $routeProvider.
                            when('/project/:id', {
                                controller: 'CommentsCtrl'
                            }).
                            otherwise({
                                redirectTo: '/'
                            });
                })
              .controller('CommentsCtrl',function($scope,$http,$routeParams){
                  $scope.comments = [];
                  $scope.param = $routeParams.id;
              });
```

Update:

In html I just have module , `CommentsCtrl` and  `<div ng-view></div>` inside `CommentsCtrl` like this:

```
<div ng-controller="CommentsCtrl">
  <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the result if you  `console.log($routeParams)` ?

Comment: Please add you html structure for more info, including ng-view

Comment: I was quicker :) - Remove ng-controller

Comment: Why to remove `ng-controller` ?

Comment: ngRoute assigns the Controller `controller: 'CommentsCtrl'`, you're doubling it

Comment: Ok, but how can now to assign param to `CommentsCtrl`?

Comment: it's already assigned on `when('/project/:id',`. Also, why don't you have a template for your view?

Comment: is there any why to print params?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've put my comments into an answer for better explanation.

You have to adjust your html structure to look like this:

```
<div>
  <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

Remove ng-controller, because ngRoute assigns the controller, as you can see in your config:

```
[...]
  $routeProvider.
    when('/project/:id', {
        controller: 'CommentsCtrl'
    })
```

Then CommentsCtrl will get $routeParams.id as a parameter.

If you should need a wrapping controller, you'll have to define a different one, like 'AppCtrl' or something. But it must not match a controller used with ngRoute.

---

This is the simplest example I could assemble for how to use ngRoute:
http://plnkr.co/edit/JSwafRF2AavvlWtsnjus?p=preview

You can test it in the fullscreen view, by modifying the url. I couldn't get the links running on plnkr up to now

#### Update:

There's some things to mention, considering my example code:

- With plunker, I have to use the hashes (#), because to server doesn't allow html5 style links. This might be different for your app so you might leave out the hashes.
- I've removed the project path in my route config for simplicity

If this doesn't help at all, it might help if you provide a live view of your app, so I can verify specifically what doesn't work or whats wrong.

Comment: I implement this in my code, but problem is I always get `Here we have no params` also I don't know why on my url is added # and looks like this: `/project/3#/`

Comment: Please see my plunk again, I've just added links and a wrapping controller. Maybe helps

Comment: I found solution here: https://scotch.io/quick-tips/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag